# Create a database in CloudVPS

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cloud, cloud-storage

Currently I'm working with CloudVPS and I'm required to create a database in cloudVPS. So I decided to install MySql and phpMyAdmin in CloudVPS. What I want to know, is MySql already installed in cloudVPS? If it is how do I enable it?? How do I install phpMyAdmin in cloudVPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Virtual Private Servers (VPS) come only with the Operating System that you have chosen (be it Linux or Windows). Therefore you are the one who has to install everything, so you should access the VPS via ssh and install anything you need (LAMP or LEMP stack) including MySQL server, apache or nginx and phpMyAdmin.

Check out these guides by Digital Ocean:

[LEMP installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04)

[phpMyAdmin installation @ LEMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-a-lemp-server)

LEMP is with nginx and LAMP is with apache.

PS: Similar procedure for Windows, except that you run the executables
and instead of ssh you use remote desktop.